# How can I create a Zenity dialog in a Zenity progress dialog?

Tags: bash, shell-script, zenity

I want to create Zenity dialogs in a Zenity progress dialog, but doing so shows the following error.

```
You must specify a dialog type. See 'zenity --help' for details
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Remote peer disconnected
```

Below is an example of what I am trying to do

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

(
echo "33.00" ; sleep 1
echo "# step 1" ; sleep 1
var=$(zenity --file-selection  --filename="$HOME/")
echo "66.00" ; sleep 1
echo "# step 2" ; sleep 1
zenity --notification --text="test notification" ; sleep 1
echo "100.00" ; sleep 1
echo "# step 3" ; sleep 1
echo "step 3" ; sleep 1
) | zenity --progress --text=test --percentage=0
```

Comment: The example you gave actually worked with zenity (3.44.1).